# Can you create a portable application on Windows with SQL Server LocalDB?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce, localdb, embedded-database

My goal is to create a simple CRUD application in C# that has an embedded database, and does not need to be installed. I've been comparing SQL Server Compact, SQL Server Local DB, and SQL Lite. It looks like SQL Server Compact has been depreciated, and SQL Lite would require me to learn a different flavor of SQL; I'd like to stick with T-SQL.

This leaves the only two options with Local DB or Compact, and Local DB looks like the best choice.

Once I've built and compiled an application that uses Local DB would I be able to simply copy the project to a new machine and run the executable?

From what I've read, it looks like you are able to do that with SQL Server Compact, but I'd hate to install Visual Studio 2010 just to develop a portable app.

I know the latest version of .NET used for developing the application will have to be installed on the target machine, but what else needs to be installed?

Comment: You must install .NET Framework. For database, there is another option, using SQLite. File base database, no installation. If you want to develop an app, you must install Visual Studio.

Comment: SQLite is one of several portable options. Google *lightweight database C#* for many more. SQL Server LocalDB requires installation separate from your application, though I believe you can bundle the installer for it with your own installer.